# WebLogic entity doesn't get persisted

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, weblogic12c

I'm implementing database access to a Postgres database using WebLogic 12c, JPA 2.2 and Hibernate 5.

I finally solved the problem, where I couldn't make 2 separate request from the database with separate datasources, users, etc. by switching Global Transactions off.

Now my problem is that whatever I do, the entities I'd like to save are not actually saved to the database. I have the `@Transactional` on all methods where inserting happens, but nothing gets written to the DB.

I went ahead and created an interceptor for Hibernate, which logs out when and what transaction gets commited. I see that something gets commited, but the transaction I get from the method parameter is null.

I'm sure I'm overlooking something obvious, but I can't for the life of me get to know what it is

Comment: I just checked, and the entity gets the generated id we are expecting here

Comment: I just realized that I wasn't using an XA datasource, since I have a Postgres database. Testing some XA Postgres driver versions